# Android Recycle View Scrolling

Tags: android, kotlin

hi I am building chat app using firebase realtime , facing issue with scrolling to last message -Bottom- when new message received , its working fine scrolling and every thing but not showing full height for the last item

here is my code

```
binding.items.smoothScrollToPosition(adapter.itemCount);
```

if any code to scroll with offset and how to calculate offset for dynamic height for message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found soultion to use

```
layoutManager.stackFromEnd = true
```

final code is

```
 val layoutManager = binding.items.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager
                layoutManager.stackFromEnd = true
                binding.items.smoothScrollToPosition(adapter.itemCount)
```